# Footnotemarker as part of the running footnotetext

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

How can I change the footnote marker in the footnote so that it is in normal footnote font and part of the running footnote text?

Minimum working example of what I have now:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[side,marginal]{footmisc}    
\usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{marginfix}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\def\footnotelayout{\color{gray}}

\begin{document}
Text text text.\footnote{footnote text}
\end{document}
```

In this example, the marker is in superscript, negatively indented, and in black. I would like it to be in normal font, with no indentation, followed by an en-dash, and in grey like the rest of the footnote. Ideally, it would look something like this:

[image: example of the desired footnote]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in `memoir` without using the `footmisc` package.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\footmarkstyle{\color{gray}#1 -- } % color of marker
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{0em}    % don't indent marker
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}      % don't indent text
\renewcommand{\foottextfont}{\color{gray}\footnotesize} % color and size of text
\footnotesinmargin % put footnotes in the margin

\begin{document}
Text text text.\footnote{First footnote}
\lipsum[1]

More text.\footnote{Another footnote with a text exceeding one line.}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

See Chapter **12 Page notes** in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The following might suffice; some patches to how the footnote is handled. Updates include

- `\footnote` - storing the footnote formatting with the footnote number for later use in the text; and
- `\@makefnmark` - changed the regular way footnotes are set (as a superscript) to being in-line. Also updated the overlapping nature of the footnote mark.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[side,marginal]{footmisc}    
\usepackage[raggedrightboxes]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{marginfix}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}

\def\footnotelayout{\color{gray}}

\makeatletter
\let\old@makefnmark\@makefnmark
\def\@makemarginfnmark{\hbox{\@thefnmark~--~}}% How footnote text numbers are formatted

\pretocmd{\@makefntext}{%
  \let\@makefnmark\@makemarginfnmark% Remove superscript in footnote text
  \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\footnotelayout\thempfn}% Add footnote format to footnote text number
}{}{}
% Restore superscript formatting of footnote markers
\apptocmd{\@makefntext}{\let\@makefnmark\old@makefnmark}{}{}
% In-line formatting of of footnote text number
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{\llap{\hb@xt@ -\footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}}}{\@makefnmark}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec malesuada luctus 
tortor eu vehicula.\footnote{This is the first footnote.} Suspendisse a quam eu 
elit tristique ultricies. Suspendisse ut eros a odio fermentum scelerisque. Sed 
dignissim sapien placerat felis euismod laoreet. Quisque eu tellus ac justo 
volutpat fringilla. Aliquam elementum, odio in bibendum elementum, ante odio 
dignissim enim, eu tincidunt justo sapien eu massa. Aenean nunc nunc, accumsan 
rhoncus luctus ut, imperdiet quis leo. Etiam facilisis maximus leo, placerat 
mollis dolor interdum in.\footnote{This is the second footnote, which runs multiple
lines to show that there is no indentation.} Pellentesque rutrum neque vitae 
luctus aliquam. Quisque luctus fermentum ornare. Nam efficitur mauris mauris, ut 
molestie eros laoreet sed. Etiam purus ex, porttitor at cursus ac, iaculis 
fringilla leo.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm. However, Peter's solution ultimately makes the tweaks redundant.